# Parsing json to swift constants

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to parse all the data from the endpoint and assign it to constants so I can use them in my ViewController class. My biggest problem is assigning each item of the "key" array to constants. Can anyone help me out?

```
 static func fetchRates(completionHandler: (current: [Currency]) -> ()) {

    let urlString = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/all"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let json = try(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(location!, options: .MutableContainers))
            let tickerData = [Currency]()

            for key in json as! [String : AnyObject] {

             }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completionHandler(current: tickerData)
            })

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err)
        }

    }).resume()
  }
```

This is the response from the endpoint.

```
  {
"AUD": {
 "24h_avg": 621.17,
 "ask": 624.12,
 "bid": 620.3,
"last": 620.45,
"timestamp": "Mon, 23 May 2016 20:01:16 -0000",
"total_vol": 671.28
 },
 "BRL": {
"24h_avg": 1725.77,
"ask": 1748.83,
"bid": 1731.8,
"last": 1738.64,
"timestamp": "Mon, 23 May 2016 20:01:16 -0000",
"total_vol": 534.19
 },
 "CAD": {
"24h_avg": 579.2,
"ask": 579.27,
"bid": 573.57,
"last": 577.42,
"timestamp": "Mon, 23 May 2016 20:01:16 -0000",
"total_vol": 413.81
 },
```

Comment: Can you print your json and share result so that I can give a concrete example?

Comment: I added the response to my question. @AkshanshThakur

Comment: The key "array" is a dictionary, how to assign the values depends on the structure of the class `Currency`

Comment: If it is a dictionary how would I assign the elements of each item to be a constant? Can you give me an example of how the class `Currency` would look like? @vadian

Comment: `Currency` must be declared somewhere otherwise you get a `unresolved identifier` error.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
for (key, value) in (json as! [String: AnyObject]) {
    let currencyData = value as! [String: AnyObject]
    // key is the currency code: AUD, BRL, etc
    // currencyData is the details: ask, bid, last, ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough and ready solution, but it's a start you can build on.

Let's start by defining some convenience types:

```
// Define a handy result type
// See https://github.com/antitypical/Result if you want a more detailed implementation.
public enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(ErrorType)
}

// Define an error type for inconsistentData
public enum DataError: ErrorType {
    case NoData
}

// Define a struct to hold a Currency
public struct Currency: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {
    let currencyCode: String
    let dayAverage: Double
    let ask: Double
    let bid: Double
    let last: Double
    let timestamp: String
    let totalVolume: Double

    // This makes it easier to debug
    public var description: String {
        return "currencyCode: \(currencyCode), dayAverage: \(dayAverage), ask: \(ask), bid: \(bid), last: \(last), timestamp: \(timestamp), totalVolume: \(totalVolume)"
    }

    public init(currencyCode: String,
                dayAverage: Double,
                ask: Double,
                bid: Double,
                last: Double,
                timestamp: String,
                totalVolume: Double) {
        self.currencyCode = currencyCode
        self.dayAverage = dayAverage
        self.ask = ask
        self.bid = bid
        self.last = last
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.totalVolume = totalVolume
    }
}

// Make sure your structs conform to Equatable.
public func == (lhs: Currency, rhs: Currency) -> Bool {
    return
        lhs.currencyCode == rhs.currencyCode &&
            lhs.dayAverage == rhs.dayAverage &&
            lhs.ask == rhs.ask &&
            lhs.bid == rhs.bid &&
            lhs.last == rhs.last &&
            lhs.timestamp == rhs.timestamp &&
            lhs.totalVolume == rhs.totalVolume
}

// I like to define convenience initialisers outside of the struct. Keeps things less coupled.
public extension Currency {

    public init?(currencyCode: String, values: [String : AnyObject]) {
        guard
            let dayAverage = values["24h_avg"] as? Double,
            let ask = values["ask"] as? Double,
            let bid = values["bid"] as? Double,
            let last = values["last"] as? Double,
            let timestamp = values["timestamp"] as? String,
            let totalVolume = values["total_vol"] as? Double
            else { return nil }

        self = Currency(currencyCode: currencyCode,
                        dayAverage: dayAverage,
                        ask: ask,
                        bid: bid,
                        last: last,
                        timestamp: timestamp,
                        totalVolume: totalVolume)
    }
}
```

Now the function to fetch the values can be written as:

```
// The function to fetch the currencies.
// Use a richer type for the completion parameter. It is either a success with a list of currencies or an error.
public func fetchRates(completionHandler: (Result<[Currency]>) -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/all")! // Force unwrapped as we assume this is a valid URL

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, _, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(.Error(error))
            return
        }

        do {
            guard
                let data = data,
                // Being generous with the type of the result because there is a top level key that is the timestamp not related to a currency.
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]
                else {
                    completionHandler(.Error(DataError.NoData))
                    return
            }

            var currencies = [Currency]()

            for (key, value) in json {
                guard
                    // Make sure that the values we are about to pass on are of the correct type.
                    let value = value as? [String : AnyObject],
                    let currency = Currency(currencyCode: key, values: value)
                    else { continue }
                currencies.append(currency)
            }

            print(currencies)

            completionHandler(.Success(currencies))

        } catch {
            completionHandler(.Error(error))
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

And you can run this function with the completion handlers as:

```
fetchRates { result in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        switch result {
        case .Success(let currencies):
            for currency in currencies {
                print(currency)
            }
        case .Error(let error):
            print(error)
        }        
    }
}
```

You can download the playground where you can see all this working at:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/585261/Currency.playground.zip